# how do I compare two .js files in powershell

Tags: javascript, git, powershell, github

I'm using Udicity's free GitHub Tutorial and I'm trying to compare two .js files using powershell.

command line:

C:\Users\BOBBY1\Udacity\gitAndGitHub>

the files are:

game_old.js

game_new.js

what command do I need to type at the command line to compare them? The "FC" command they suggest in the tutorial does not seem to work.

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not seem to work"?

Comment: I get an error - Format-Custom : A postional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'game_old.js' .At line:1 char:1

Comment: What command are you actually issuing?

Comment: the command i wrote was "FC game_old.js game_new.js".  Am I not using the command correctly?

Comment: Is it possible that your issuance of `fc` is not actually be invoking PowerShell's file compare?  Type `fc /?` or `fc -?` and see what the output is.  Perhaps there's another `fc` executable on your path.  also, try issuing your command as `fc.exe file1 file2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fc` is an alias to the PowerShell's `Format-Custom` cmdlet:

```
Get-Alias -Name 'fc'

CommandType     Name                             Version    Source
-----------     ----                             -------    ------
Alias           fc -> Format-Custom
```

To use Windows's `fc` command you should type `fc.exe file1 file2`, as [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024832/marc) suggested in comments.

To [compare files with PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2013/11/29/using-powershell-to-compare-diff-files/), use `Compare-Object`:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content file1.txt) (Get-Content file2.txt) | 
    Sort { $_.InputObject.ReadCount }
```